# How to use ZFS on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, zfs

It seem that Ubuntu 16.04 LTS supports the ZFS filesystem. But how do I use it?
I'm sorry, I don't know very much about ZFS, but it sounds good. I want it.

Comment: If I may make a suggestion: practice with ZFS on a virtual machine or some other non-critical/disposable data machine. As you learn how it works, you're bound to blow away the raid data. I did this a handful of times with live data that is now forever gone

Answer (score 22):

First off, use ZFS only if you really want it. See the [Use Cases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZFS) to know if you really need ZFS.

ZFS is supported only in 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 installs. To install it run:

```
sudo apt-get install zfsutils-linux
```

To learn more, you can see the [reference](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/ZFS) on Ubuntu or [this](https://pthree.org/2012/04/17/install-zfs-on-debian-gnulinux/) excellent documentation.

A good introduction can also be found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/175159/an-introduction-to-the-z-file-system-zfs-for-linux/)

Answer (score 9):

As **root** in an Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS this works:

```
apt update
apt install -y zfs
```

You are then done. You can check it is there by doing:

```
zfs list
```

you can then create a pool by doing:

```
zpool create -f zxavi /dev/sdb
```

or whatever disk you want to use; and after that:

```
zpool status
```

Boom, done!

Answer (score 4):

Since I only have 1 reputation, I can neither upvote nor comment on [Xavi's answer, which is the correct one](https://askubuntu.com/a/857784/529523). Things *not* to do include:

- **Do not** waste your time with <s>[`mountall`](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-ZFS-mountall-FAQ-and-troubleshooting)</s>, all of that Wiki page is obsolete as far as Xenial is concerned;
- **Do not** install a package named <s>`ubuntu-zfs`</s>, or use the <s>[so-called "stable" ZFS PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ezfs-native/+archive/stable)</s>.

Comment: May you come with more detail in support of your advise?

Comment: @DomQ: would be nice if you could provide some explanation for your recommendation.